# Black screen after cloning just the Windows System Partition

Tags: linux, windows, boot, partitioning, clone

On my laptop I have a UEFI dual-boot system windows+arch linux with both systems encrypted - the Windows with the VeraCrypt and the linux with LUKS - I followed [this guide](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:qPnmAU-LEkYJ:https://joshrosso.com/c/arch-windows-install/&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=pl). At the end my disk looked like this

```
Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG MZVLB512HBJQ-000L7              
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: DCABFC50-29EB-450F-A77F-A78B2E1091AE

Device             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme1n1p1      2048     534527    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/nvme1n1p2    534528     567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme1n1p3    567296  588566527 587999232 280.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme1n1p4 998166528 1000214527   2048000  1000M Windows recovery environmen
/dev/nvme1n1p5 588566528  589615103   1048576   512M Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme1n1p6 589615104  998166527 408551424 194.8G Linux filesystem
```

Recently I've bought a new nvme hard drive and I wanted to move my Windows installation to it + expand the linux to use the old disk entirely. I'd like to move just the windows system partition `/dev/nvme1n1p3`.
The steps I did already:

1. I decrypted the windows system partition using veracrypt
2. I created a new larger ntfs partition on my new disk

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 980 PRO 1TB                 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 8B796ABF-C9FE-496F-A031-DD179E1CDEEC

Device         Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    34      32767      32734    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p2 32768 1953523711 1953490944 931.5G Microsoft basic data
```

3. I cloned my windows system partition `/dev/nvme1n1p3` to the larger one `/dev/nvme0n1p2` using `clonezilla`  `partition to partition` clone
4. I created a bootable windows usb, went to the command prompt and did:

```
Diskpart
> list volume
> select volume 2 // select EFI partition
> assign letter=Z 
bcdboot C:\WINDOWS /l pl-pl /s Z: /f UEFI // C: is the new larger partition
```

Now when I go to the boot menu and pick `Windows Boot Manager` it runs but instead of getting windows login screen I get a black screen and mouse arrow with loading spinner going on and on.

However when I do:

```
Diskpart
> list volume
> select volume 2 // select EFI partition
> assign letter=Z 
bcdboot D:\WINDOWS /l pl-pl /s Z: /f UEFI // D: is the old partition
```

and go to the `Windows Boot Manager` I can boot my old windows system. I tried to use windows startup repair but it didn't work.

1. What do you think I do wrong ? I think it has something to do with the correct EFI setup but I don't know how to fix it
2. Maybe I miss marking the new partition as bootable or something ?
3. Does it have something to do with the fact that EFI partition is on a different drive than the new/cloned Windows system partition ?
4. Do you think I need to remove the old windows partition first because I can't have them both at the same time ?
5. Is it possible that the new/cloned system was corrupted ?

Comment: Lots of questions which makes this an opinion question. Can you set up the new disk properly (fresh) and the install / recover what you need?

Comment: Lots of questions don't make this opinion, necessarily, but it's still not allowed here. We need a single question that can be answered with a single answer. Edit your question to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it. Basically the problem was with using clonezilla to copy the old windows partition to the new partition; when I used the macrium reflect to copy the partition and did the rest the same as before it worked.
Thanks for help !